# Yehoshua 5:15 - Why is the ground considered holy?

Tags: tanach, midrash, yehoshua-joshua

> "וַיֹּ֩אמֶר֩ שַׂר־צְבָ֨א יְהֹוָ֜ה אֶל־יְהוֹשֻׁ֗עַ שַׁל־נַֽעַלְךָ֙ מֵעַ֣ל רַגְלֶ֔ךָ כִּ֣י הַמָּק֗וֹם אֲשֶׁ֥ר אַתָּ֛ה עֹמֵ֥ד עָלָ֖יו קֹ֣דֶשׁ ה֑וּא וַיַּ֥עַשׂ יְהוֹשֻׁ֖עַ כֵּֽן:"

> "And the captain of the Lord's host said to Joshua, Remove your shoe from your foot; for the place upon which you stand is holy. And Joshua did so." [Joshua.5.15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Joshua.5.15?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=en)

Why is the ground considered holy that Yehoshua was standing on?

Comment: Good point, especially because exactly the same language is used for Moses: https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%9E%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%A7%D6%97%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D6%B2%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B6%D6%A5%D7%A8%20%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B8%D6%9B%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D6%B9%D7%9E%D6%B5%D6%A5%D7%93%20%D7%A2%D6%B8%D7%9C%D6%B8%D6%96%D7%99%D7%95&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance

Answer (score 3):

The [Kli Yakar](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39879&st=&pgnum=128) on that passuk explains that the malach was introducing Hashem (who speaks to Yehoshua in 6:2) and therefore the place he was standing was holy because the Shechina was there.

He then continues to explain why here it was only one shoe and by Moshe it was both, as well as here it says makom and there it says land. He says that since Yehoshua was in Eretz Yisroel it uses a different word.

Answer (score 2):

The Midrash ([Bereishit Rabbah 97:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.97.3?lang=bi)) explains:

"And it was when Yehoshua was in Yericho, and he lifted up his eyes and saw, and behold, a man stood over him... and he [the man] said 'No, but I am captain of the LORD's host and have just arrived...'" (Joshua 5:13-14). Rabbi Yehoshua in the name of Rabbi Chanina son of Yitzchak, he cried out from within his toenails, as it says "And he said, 'I am a captain of the LORD's host'" (ibid.) - a captain of the Lofty Ones am I, **and every place that I am seen, the Holy Blessed One is seen.**

It seems that your question is addressed by and answered by the [MeAvur HaAretz on Yehoshua 5:15](https://www.sefaria.org/MeAvur_HaAretz%3B_on_Joshua.8.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אז נתגלה ליהושע שר צבא ה', שבא כדי לצאת לפני העם בקרב (יהושע ה, יג). המלאך ציוה את יהושע להסיר את נעליו מעל רגליו, כי המקום אשר הוא דורך עליו, קודש הוא (יהושע ה, טו). צו זה נראה תמוה במקצת, שכן האדמה במקום הפגישה עם המלאך לא היתה שונה מחלקי אדמה אחרים בארץ. כל ארץ ישראל קדושה, ולא מוטלת עלינו חובה להלך בה יחפים. נסיון השוואה לסנה יראה מלאכותי, שהרי שם התגלה ה' והיה על משה לנהוג בו כבוד. אך מדוע יהא צורך לחלוק כבוד למלאך?
> 14
> אלא שהמלאך גילה ליהושע, שכדי לכבוש את הארץ עלינו להסיר את המחיצות בינינו לבינה. מתוך הסרת המחיצות והגישה הבלתי אמצעית, מתוך ההזדהות עם הטבע הארצי של ארץ ישראל, ההתמסרות וההשתייכות לארץ עצמה, נוכל לצאת לקרב ונוכל לנצח ולפעול, למען המשך הופעת קוממיותנו הלאומית.

Comment: +1 for effort, unfortunately, it does not fit the language, as it says "מקום", not "ארץ". That specific PLACE was somewhat holy.

Comment: @AlBerko It also doesn’t address the command to Yehoshuah who was specifically told to remove only a single sandal, not both. These important details are an indication that the author of the commentary is only speculating intellectually and doesn’t truly know this subject.